# find maximum values for each row in list in r?

Tags: r, max

I have a lists of list in r. I want to find maximum values for each row in each list.

Here is my data:

```
$`01-2020`
$`01-2020`$h1
 [1] 5 5 5 1 6 1 6 4 4 2

$`01-2020`$h2
[1] 5 1 7 0 8


$`02-2020`
$`02-2020`$h1
[1] 0 0 0 0 1 2 1 1 1

$`02-2020`$h2
[1] 10  8  7  5  4
```

and its structure:

```
data<-list(`01-2020` = list(h1 = c(5, 5, 5, 1, 6, 1, 6, 4, 4, 2), h2 = c(5, 
    1, 7, 0, 8)), `02-2020` = list(h1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 
    1), h2 = c(10, 8, 7, 5, 4)))
```

I want to obtain these output values:

```
$`01-2020`
$`01-2020`$h1
[1] 6

$`01-2020`$h2
[1] 8


$`02-2020`
$`02-2020`$h1
[1] 2

$`02-2020`$h2
[1] 10
```

And also I see outputs like this:
[image]

But what I want to see is like the example below. I mean, without blue down arrow. also like `double[2x1]`, not separate `double[1]` rows :
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `rrapply`

```
library(rrapply)
rrapply(data, f = max)
```

-output

```
#$`01-2020`
#$`01-2020`$h1
#[1] 6

#$`01-2020`$h2
#[1] 8


#$`02-2020`
#$`02-2020`$h1
#[1] 2

#$`02-2020`$h2
#[1] 10
```

Or as `@27 ϕ 9` suggested in the comments, a `base R` alternative is `rapply`

```
rapply(data, max, how = "list")
```

---

Or another option is a nested `lapply` from `base R`

```
lapply(data, function(x) lapply(x, max))
```

---

Or to get the structure correctly

```
 out <- lapply(data, function(x) unname(sapply(x, max)))
```

[image]

Comment: they all worked fine, thanks. but what should I do to arrange my output like the picture above (I want to see double[2x1] instead of separate double[1] rows. and I want to see 01-2020 and 02-2020 directly (without blue down arrow)

Comment: @HüsamettinTayşi Based on the first structure showed as expected, the output is the same `$`01-2020`
$`01-2020`$h1`

Comment: @HüsamettinTayşi how about using `sapply` instead of `lapply` for the third solution i.e. `lapply(data, function(x) sapply(x, max))`

Comment: @HüsamettinTayşi can you check my last piece of code in the update